# Using Sql Server CE with generated DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, dataset, sql-server-ce

I am using a SQL-Server CE database with a table Accounts in my project. I created the database and it shows up in the Data Connections and shows the entries ive already added by hand.

Next i went to Data Sources and added a new data source, connected it to the database from the data connections, it showed me the table and i was able to "import" it. Visual Studio then created the typed dataset and now id like to use it.

Ok, so far so good, now i have created a new instance of the AccountDataSet (thats how i named it) and wanted to see if my entries are loaded, but sadly it says the Accounts-Table is empty. So i guess there is no connection to my database done in the generated dataset. Also if i add a new row to the account table using the AccountDataSet-instance it remains there during runtime but it wont be saved to the database.

Is there a way to "connect" the dataset directly to my database? Ive seen a lot of different postings with Ole-databases and so on, but so far i couldnt find a solution to my problem.

Comment: Look in your bin/debug folder for a copy of the database with data in it :-)

Comment: Sadly no, the database is actually in the same folder as the program, but i changed the programs path, the behavior is the same and it also does not create a copy of the database.